# How do I get Jython-Django to work with Postgresql JDBC

Tags: django, postgresql, jython

I have tried to setup an instance of Django on Jython using Postgresql. I can't get Django to talk to Postgresql.  Can someone help me figure out what is wrong?**

So far, I have the following system installed for development:

Windows 7
JDK7 (x86)
Jython Version 2.7b2
Django-1.6.5
django-jython 1.7.0b2(Database backends and management commands, for development underDjango/Jython)
postgresql-9.3.5-1-windows-x64.exe
Eclipse-PyDev

I was able to run the server and database, but now I am having issues with configuring Django to work with the Postgresql database.

I followed the configuration steps here:
https://pythonhosted.org/django-jython/database-backends.html#postgresql

My settings.py file has the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'doj.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'gate',
        'USER': 'gate',
        'PASSWORD': 'test',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

When I check my class path:

```
C:\>echo %CLASSPATH%
C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin.;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\li
b\ext\QTJava.zip
```

I have the JDBC file postgresql-9.3-1102.jdbc41.jar in the lib folder listed above.

Error Message from Django
File "C:\jython2.7b2\Lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 131, in load_backend raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
        django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'doj.db.backends.postgresql' isn't an available 
database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
u'mysql', u'oracle', u'postgresql_psycopg2', u'sqlite3'
Error was: No module named schema

Comment: gah, please read the formatting guide and *use the preview*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are using the wrong version of Django.
Jython-Django is compatible only starting from 1.7.

See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/jython/